# Facebook ShareLinkContent not working propertly when fb app is not installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app I have an option to share something on Facebook. I'm using ShareLinkContent because I want to use facebook's app links. It works perfectly when I have the facebook app installed on the phone, but, when I don't, the facebook webview shows me an error like: "an error ocurred, please try again later". My code looks like this:

```
private static ShareLinkContent.Builder getDefaultFbBuilder(Event event) {
    return new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(BASE_FB_APP_LINK + "?eventId=" + event.getId()))
            .setContentTitle(event.getTitle())
            .setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL)
            .setContentDescription(UtilsDate.getStringFromDate(event.getDate()) + " | " + event.getAddress());
}
```

I have no Idea what is happening since it works when the app is installed or if I don't set the imageUrl.

Comment: did u get anhy solution or not ??

Comment: @Sudhanshu  No, I didn't. For now I just check if the app is installed or not and only add the picture to the intent if it is...

Comment: Please modify the code snippet in your question to include the actual parameters (and not variable/constant names like `BASE_FB_APP_LINK`). That way others can see the full picture of your issue.